# Formatting datetime using joda-time and parseDateTime ignoring fraction of second

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to format the time I am getting with a certain time zone.
The input date string I am getting is of the type "2015-09-21T09:00:00+02:00"
The code I am using to do this is

```
DateTimeZone fromTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").withZone(fromTimeZone);    
DateTime cetDateTime = fmt.parseDateTime(inputDate);

return cetDateTime.toString();
```

However this returns "2015-09-21T09:00:00.000+02:00" with the fraction of second added. Is there any way to suppress the fraction in the above string?

Comment: You haven't formatted the `DateTime`.

Comment: Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the `DateTime` any way you want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
return fmt.print(cetDateTime);
```